# Python, adding a "cashback" for every third iteration

Tags: python, class, if-statement, methods, attributes

Our professor gave us a problem of adding a "cashback" mechanism for an online store setting. We are tasked to use a parent class and a child class to use inheritance.

Goal: to add 50 after every third purchase

What I have so far:

Parent:

```
class Shop:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__balance = 0

    def getBalance(self):
        return self.__balance

    def loadWallet(self, amount):
        self.__balance += amount

    def purchase(self, amount_val):
        if amount_val <= self.__balance:
            self.__balance -= amount_val

        else:
            print("Insufficient Funds")
```

Child:

```
class ShopCashBack(Shop):

    def __init__(self, base_val=0):
        self.__numpurchase = base_val
        Shop.__init__(self)

    def getPurch(self):
        return self.__numpurchase

    def purchase(self, amount_val):
        self.__numpurchase += 1

        Shop.purchase(self, amount_val)

        if self.__numpurchase % 3 == 0:
            result = self.getBalance() + 50
            print(result)
```

Input:

```
user = ShopCashBack()

user.loadWallet(5000)
user.purchase(299)
print(user.getBalance())

user.loadWallet(3000)
print(user.getBalance())
user.purchase(4990)
print(user.getBalance())

user.purchase(1607)
print(user.getBalance())
```

Result:

```
4701
7701
2711
1154
1104
```

Desired Result:
where 1154 is 1104 + 50 (the balance after the third purchase)

```
4701
7701
2711
1154
```

Comment: here `result = self.getBalance() + 50` you need to update `self.__balance` as well and not just print the result

Comment: You need to add the cash back amount after calling super().purchase(...). This ensures the parent class updates the balance first, then you can add the bonus:
`class ShopCashBack(Shop):
    # ...
    def purchase(self, amount_val):
        self.__numpurchase += 1
        super().purchase(amount_val)  # Call parent method first
        if self.__numpurchase % 3 == 0:
            self.__balance += 50  # Then add bonus`

Comment: thank you! both of these work, it is just that we're not allowed to use super() yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change child perchase method

from this:

```
if self.__numpurchase % 3 == 0:
    result = self.getBalance() + 50
    print(result)
```

to this:

```
if self.__numpurchase % 3 == 0:
    self.loadWallet(50)
```

because you don't do anything to balance with `result = self.getBalance() + 50` balance stays the same after this line

Comment: thank you for this! I thought of the getBalance as the balance I have to add to. I should've thought of the loadWallet as the cashback works that way.

Comment: When you call getBalance you get its return and that's it, you should see it like getBalance doesn't exists anymore after its execution, and in fact instead of getBalance you have just number that getBalance returned. After that to this number you add 50 and nothing happens, there is just new number that goes to nowhere when your program executes next line of code. balance is a name within an instance (=self) namespace, to make changes you need you always have to change that name of an instance namespace.